# how to ping an intranet server with android emulator

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, ping, intranet

Is it possible to do a ping request inside the android emulator of AndroidStudio?

I would like to know it, because i want to request a server in the intranet, but all i found til yet was how to ping the computer running the IDE.